# Prevent an input text to reset to default width when using jQuery autocomplete ui

Tags: css, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using a Wordpress plugin based on jQuery autocomplete UI here:
https://milesopedia.com/questions-reponses

I set a specific width for the input text element. Somehow when the input text is filled and during the search, its width fallback to the default one temporary.

I tried to change the width with the following class but without success : `.ui-autocomplete-loading` `.ui-autocomplete-input` `.ufaq-text-input`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS that sets input width is inside div with id ufaq-faq-list. When you type something, that element is replaced with another element and so you lose all styles defined inside it.

Comment: Thanks for the help!